# Understanding the firefox source code

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-developer-tools

We are trying to redirect the system calls made by firefox browser to our application. The application will check the return of the system calls. 
To go about this we need to debug the firefox and we need to enable prints. The prints will help us understand the execution flow of code.
We tried enabling NS_PRINTING through .mozconfig but we are not sure if its working as we cannot see any relevant prints during execution of the nightly.
Please help.

Comment: It's unclear what your exact question is. Maybe you could rephrase it so we can help.

Comment: we have a project we are working on. that would allow us to monitor the system calls that the browser makes, to check if they are reading any confidential information. to redirect the calls made by the browser to our application we need to understand the way browser works. we thought enabling NS_PRINTING would help us understand that. how to enable NS_PRINTING.